# Better approach to write Junit5 tests for spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, junit5, hamcrest

I created a Test class:

```
void comp() throws IOException{
Foo foo=new Foo()
String file=readFile("xyz.txt")
Model model=foo.generate(file)
Assert.assertEquals(model.getMapA().size(),0);
Assert.assertEquals(model.getMapB().size(),0);
Assert.assertEquals(model.getListC().size(),10);

}
```

Is this a good approach to writing the Junit test? I mean all the asserts inside one method. An alternate approach I could think of is to have a setup method that will generate the model class and a separate method for checking the size of each attribute. The class `Foo` is a controller class in a spring boot application.

I am using Junit5. I also saw that Hamcrest is popular, but the last release was on Jul 09, 2012 Which raises a question should we use it or not

Comment: What are you even trying to test here? `Foo` is completely irrelevant to your test-case. A good practice is to only have one assertion in the test to only test one functionality. And only checking for size is not enough to have a good unit test.

Comment: @Garuno Thanks I updated the code. So even if I am checking multiple-size statements it's better to have them all in a separate method? I will add more test cases to make it stronger. Also, what do you suggest using `Junit5` or `Hamcrest`? Although the test case I am building here are pretty simple

Comment: everything in your question is opinion based, write the way it is more readable, add comments on what each test case does, etc. Whatever your organization already does, go from there.

Comment: As far as I know Hamcrest is just an assertion library similar to assertJ, so you can't use it to write tests alone. You always need Junit and can then decide if you want to add hamecrest or assertJ or whatever assertion library you like.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem in your test scenario is when the first assertion fails you do not see results of next assertions, I would recommend to start using [AssertJ assertions](https://assertj.github.io/doc/), in that case your assertions would look like (very basic example though):

```java
Model model=foo.generate(file);
SoftAssertions.assertSoftly(softly -> {
    softly.assertThat(model.getMapA()).isEmpty();
    softly.assertThat(model.getMapB()).isEmpty();
    softly.assertThat(model.getListC()).hasSize(10);
});
```